# What is missing to show the desktop-dirname in the frame title?

Tags: frames, desktop, backquote

I tried to get the value of `desktop-dirname` into the title of a frame:

```
(setq frame-title-format '("%b Desktop: "
                           (car (last (split-string desktop-dirname "/" t)))))
```

The `(car ...)` part evaluates just fine to `"Something"`, but I don't
see it in the frame title. I see only `"buffer.el Desktop:"` and I don't
understand why. What's missing?

Comment: BTW, rather than split-string+last, I'd use `(file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name desktop-dirname))`.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. That's right what I wanted but didn't find because of my lack of elisp-knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a literal list as the second arg to `setq`.  Instead, you want to substitute the value of the `(car...)` sexp.

You can do that using a backquote construction, telling it to *evaluate* that `(car...)` sexp and use the result of the evaluation.

You want this:

```el
(setq frame-title-format   `("%b Desktop: "
                             ,(car (last (split-string desktop-dirname "/" t)))))
```

or (equivalently) this:

```el
(setq frame-title-format  (list "%b Desktop: "
                                (car (last (split-string desktop-dirname "/" t)))))
```